# how to make a responsive image map when media query changed?

Tags: reactjs, sass, responsive-design, img-area-select-jquery

I had this problem with making responsive image map when I made some map on than in media queries the position of areas was changing so it make me crazy than I found this way
what is the way?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for long day that how I should write a code that links should not change when the position of an image changed in media queries so I found this way the best.

1. first go to this https://zaneray.com/responsive-image-map/ website and add your local image address from the webpage that you are working than add links in every place of your image that you want
2. add a div before your image and make it position relative
3. add the img tag and copy all the urls from that site

[image: this is the point in image that I want to link in some place]

```
                <div className="Afghan-map">
                <img src={map} className="Afg-map" />
                <a
                    href="your url"
                    title="Balkh"
                    className="balkh province"
                />
                <a
                    href="hyour url"
                    title="Jallab abbad"
                    className="jallal-abbad province"
                />
                <a
                    href="your url"
                    title="Badghis"
                    className="badghis province"
                />
                <a
                    href="your url"
                    title="Kabul"
                    className="kabul province"
                />
                <a
                    href="your url"
                    title="Herat"
                    className="herat province"
                />
            </div>
```

4. than add your style like this.

   .Afghan-map {
   position: relative;

   .province {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   }

   .balkh {
   left: 44.83%;
   top: 21.83%;
   width: 7.48%;
   height: 12.1%;
   }

   .jallal-abbad {
   left: 63.27%;
   top: 43.55%;
   width: 5.71%;
   height: 6.25%;
   }

   .badghis {
   left: 25.39%;
   top: 34.82%;
   width: 10.42%;
   height: 10.22%;
   }

   .kabul {
   left: 57.41%;
   top: 41.57%;
   width: 4.48%;
   height: 5.56%;
   }

   .herat {
   left: 12.81%;
   top: 39.88%;
   width: 12.04%;
   height: 17.36%;
   }
   }